# Compound sentence or simple sentence. (We sang and danced all night)

Tags: transformation

I am actually confused to know whether the following sentence is compound or simple sentence.

My sentence is: ( She sang and danced all night). As far as, I know that this sentence has 'conjunction' which is joining two sentences together here. But I have seen somewhere that it's a simple sentence. 
To me, it's a compound sentence but in longman's book, I studied that (two or more finite verbs can be joined to make a simple sentence.)

Comment: Why is it important to know if it's a compound sentence?

Comment: @Andrew Because I have to know about it. And I am very confused about it. Secondly, I have discussed this sentence with different experts on Facebook. They called it as a compound sentence but in Longman's book, it is giving the statement that I added.

Comment: So you're just trying to prove that the "experts" are wrong?  Will knowing if can be labelled as a "compound sentence" help you write correct sentences in the future?   I'm just helping you get the best answer to your question.

Comment: @Andrew, kindly take things positively. I am here for positive discussion. Secondly, I mentioned experts because of citing my source nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple sentence with compound verbs, my friend. A compound sentence has two independent clauses combined with a conjunction. For example -

*They sang all night but the body guard stopped them from dancing*

Notice that if you remove *but* from this sentence, you will get

*They sang all night*
and
*the body guard stopped them from dancing*

Both the sentences can stand firm on their own and make sense independently. Combining them with any suitable conjunction will give you a compound sentence, but the sentence in your question can not be divided into two independent sentences like this. Hence, it is a simple sentence with compound verbs.

Comment: What is the role of 'and' here? Isn't it a conjunction?

Comment: This sentence has two 'finite verbs'. So how can we say that it's a simple sentence?

Comment: @Idon'tknowwhoIam. 'and' in this sentence is a conjunction. A conjunction can either join two sentences or two verbs and in this case, it is performing the task of joining two verbs together. As far as your second question goes, a simple sentence ideally should have one subject and one predicate but the subject can be compound and the verb can be compound too. 'She and I like movies', 'She likes movies and songs', 'She walks and runs all day', these are all simple sentences but with compound subjects, objects and verbs.

Comment: One of my teachers said, if there is the same idea having 'and' in the sentence then we call it as a simple sentence, like 'she danced and sang'. Is he right? Then secondly, he said, if there are two different ideas with conjunction 'and' then it can be a compound sentence. I am really confused to distinguish between them, now.

Comment: @Idon'tknowwhoIam. If you follow that advice, you will be confused to identify ideas. A simple rule of thumb is that a compound sentence is made of two independent sentences. But simple sentences do not have that property. Just because the name suggests they are simple sentences doesn't mean they are all straightforward. They can exist in many forms and types. 'You have ceased to surprise me' is a simple sentence too. As I said, just follow the rule of independent clauses and you should be fine.